# use wsdl with mule

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mule

I have a web service on a server that it use a wsdl of another company (such as company A).

Now, I want to my web service use mule architected.
I have to starting a mule server. My request should sent such as below algorithm:

My web service -> mule server -> wsdl of company A

And about response:

Wsdl of company A -> mule server -> my web service

I used “web service proxy pattern” and “wsdl redirection” for do that. So by doing this work, wsdl of company A redirected on mule server. I think that I didn’t use mule correctly because I just change url address of wsdl. There is a part in wsdl:

```
<soap:address location=””>
```

And `<xsd:schema><xsd:import namespace=””>`

This location and namespace are url address of company A. when I create stub file from wsdl, there are url address of company A in this files and annotation in stub files.

Configuration:

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="SOAP2SOAPFlow4"
  inboundAddress="http://localhost:8090/sample"
  outboundAddress="http://companyA.com/test"
  wsdlLocation="http://companyA.com/test.asmx?WSDL" />
```

Running on Mule standalone 3.3.0.

Is my work wrong? What do I change?

Comment: Hi @DavidDossot,
I use mule-standalone-3.3.0. and my Config:

`<pattern:web-service-proxy name="SOAP2SOAPFlow4"
  inboundAddress="http://localhost:8090/sample"
  outboundAddress="http://companyA.com/test"
  wsdlLocation="http://companyA.com/test.asmx?WSDL"
/>`

Comment: When you GET the WSDL from the proxy, do you GET it from http://localhost:8090/sample?WSDL?

Comment: yes @David, I get it from local address, but in schema location and soap port, there are Comapany A url address.
I want to change these addresses from compny A to local Address.